# How to give an object the same shape of another that has a different number of vertices?

Tags: modeling, objects

Basically, I have 2 premade human models, one of them is the original model, and the other one is an edited version that I sculpted some details on. For some reason, the edited version had a different number of vertices than the original version. I'm making a game mod and I need the edited version to have the same number of vertices as the original version for it to work.

I don't wanna have to sculpt the original version again cause that would take a lot of work, so is there any way to give the original version the same shape as the edited version?

Comment: Hello, maybe try a Shrinkwrap modifier?